# Why am I getting non-sinusoidal output for sinusoidal input in a mass-spring system?

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, matlab

A mass-spring system is represented by the following transfer function

$$ H(s) = \frac{s^{2} + 0.1s + 10}{s^{4} + 0.2s^{3} + 20s^{2}} $$

For a sinusoidal input I am getting a non-sinusoidal output, as shown below (input in gray, output in blue):

[image]

I am using the following MATLAB code to generate the plot:

```
t = 0:0.1:20;
u = sin(1*t);
lsim(sys_x1, u,t)
```

Comment: This should probably be in the Physics SE, but since electrical circuits can have the same transfer functions, I will attempt an answer anyway. In the time-domain, it is difficult or impossible to really input an infinite sine-wave, your input signal is zero for time < 0. Did you run your simulation long enough for the output to stabilize?  The output appears to be curving downward.

Comment: @DKNguyen gray is input signal(u) and blue is output

Comment: Then its increasing because your are driving it still. Like continuing to push a child on a swing with the same rhythm of the swinging (in resonance with the swing) so energy is continually being added to and reinforcing the system. drive your input for a bit, then stop it and watch your ouput be a decaying sinusoid (if there are losses otherwise it wil just continue to oscillate)

Comment: @Mattman944 From my understanding in LTI system output is sinusoidal of same frequency as input signal, which does not seem to be a case here

Comment: @DKNguyen But as per theory increase in energy will cause change in amplitude not in the frequency of the sinusoidal input, but in this case frequency is also different from input

Comment: You haven't waited long enough for it to settle. It is a combination of a sinewave and an integral term by the looks of it.

Comment: the frequency looks the same to me. its just a bit harder to see because the amplitude is building up. draw a straight line through the output wave and its more obvious

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about springs and masses, not *electronics*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a double integrator in the TF that inverse transforms to a ramp, which is what you're seeing added to the sinusoidal response to the sinusoidal input.

Comment: Thanks. Removing integrator gives sinusoidal output of the same frequency. But doesnt integrator add 90 degree phase without changing frequency and amplitude?

Comment: @Siddhesh Nope.  An integrator adds 90 degrees phase shift with a frequency-dependent amplitude change.  If you want to torture yourself by thinking in frequency-domain terms, it turns out that the **double** integrator, when excited by a sinusoid at anything but the exactly correct starting phase, will respond with a ramp.  This is *much easier* to see in the time domain.

Comment: @TimWescott Indeed, thats the response I am getting . The book I am referring says "for an LTI system, a sinusoidal input gives
rise to a sinusoidal output again, and at the same frequency as the input". Which seems to contradict this observation.

Comment: Another way to look at those 2 S terms in the denominaor is as a sort of "double resonance" at 0Hz.  So the transient response will have an undamped 0 Hz component of some sort (a ramp in this case).

Answer (score 1):

To complement Chu's [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/441511/110535), using [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org):

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> s = Symbol('s', complex=True)
>>> H = (s**2 + 0.1*s + 10) / (s**4 + 0.2*s**3 + 20*s**2)
```

Since the Laplace transform of the input

$$x (t) := \begin{cases} \sin(t) & \text{if } t \geq 0\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

is given by

$$ X(s) = \frac{1}{s^2+1}$$

the Laplace transform of the response is

```
>>> X =  1 / (s**2 + 1)
>>> Y =  H * X
>>> apart(Y,s)
  0.473687126080213*(0.000584726932522512*s + 1.0)   0.00131287391978728*(0.0105485232067511*s - 1.0)   0.5
- ------------------------------------------------ + ------------------------------------------------ + ---
                        2                                               2                                 2
                       s  + 1                                     0.05*s  + 0.01*s + 1.0                 s
```

In \$\LaTeX\$,

$$Y(s) = - \frac{0.473687126080213 \left(0.000584726932522512 s + 1.0\right)}{s^{2} + 1} + \frac{0.00131287391978728 \left(0.0105485232067511 s - 1.0\right)}{0.05 s^{2} + 0.01 s + 1.0} + \frac{0.5}{s^{2}}$$

Note the \$\frac{1}{s^2}\$ term, which corresponds to a **ramp** in the time domain. This is unsurprising, as the double pole at the origin ensures that the LTI system being studied is *not* BIBO-stable.

Note also that the roots of \$0.05 s^{2} + 0.01 s + 1.0\$ have negative real parts:

```
>>> solve(0.05*s**2 + 0.01*s + 1.0)
[-0.1 - 4.47101778122163*I, -0.1 + 4.47101778122163*I]
```

Thus, the response contains:

- forced response: scaled and time-shifted version of the input sinusoid \$\sin (t)\$ (for \$t \geq 0\$).
- natural response: exponentially decaying sinusoid plus ramp.